# Attiny85 code on Attiny84

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, attiny

I made OLED timer/watch using Attiny85, but as internal clock isnt accurate i need external crystal. On Attiny85 im short on pins so i am switching to Attiny84 but i have problems to compile/upload same code to Attiny84. Even if i stay on Attiny84 8mhz internal clock as on Attiny85 i still cant compile.
Im using Arduino UNO as ISP.

Error what i have:

```
WDT_Time.cpp: In function 'void setup_watchdog(uint8_t)':
WDT_Time.cpp:272: error: 'WDTCR' was not declared in this scope
WDTCR |= (1 << WDCE) | (1 << WDE);
^
In file included from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,
             from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\pgmspace.h:88,
             from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:28,
             from WDT_Time.cpp:12:
WDT_Time.cpp:276: error: 'PCIE' was not declared in this scope
   sbi(GIMSK, PCIE); // Turn on Pin Change interrupts (Tell Attiny85 we want to use pin change interrupts (can be any pin))
              ^
WDT_Time.cpp:276:3: note: in expansion of macro 'sbi'
   sbi(GIMSK, PCIE); // Turn on Pin Change interrupts (Tell Attiny85 we want to use pin change interrupts (can be any pin))
   ^
WDT_Time.cpp:277: error: 'PCMSK' was not declared in this scope
   sbi(PCMSK, PCINT3);
       ^
WDT_Time.cpp:277:3: note: in expansion of macro 'sbi'
   sbi(PCMSK, PCINT3);
   ^
'WDTCR' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are slight differences between registers, register names and registers bit names:

- `WDTCR` is named `WDTCSR`
- `PCIE` doesn't exist in `GIMSK` as there are two IO ports, so there are two pin change channels: `PCIE0` and `PCIE1`
- and `PCMSK` is similar to `PCIE`. There'll be two of them too.

Basically you have to look into both datasheets and compare what you are using and check if it's correct.

Comment: In code i changed: WDTCR to WDTCSR

Comment: and other changes:
`GIMSK  = bit (PCIE0);
  sbi(GIMSK, PCIE0); // Turn on Pin Change interrupts (Tell Attiny85 we want to use pin change interrupts (can be any pin))
  PCMSK0 = bit (PCINT1) | bit (PCINT2);
  sbi(PCMSK0, PCINT1);`
Now its working. Thanks!